# Import Error with virtualenv and django-braces when trying to import AnonymousRequiredMixin

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am getting the following error when trying to run:

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, AnonymousRequiredMixin
```

However, everything works fine in the Dev environment and the same in my prod environment., and `django-braces` is in my `virtualenv`.

Has anyone had this error or knows why it is having trouble importing `AnonymousRequiredMixin`?

```
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]     url(r'', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 25, in include
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]     __import__(name)
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]   File "/home/aaron/public_html/learnrealsql.com/asql/core/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]     from core import views
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]   File "/home/aaron/public_html/learnrealsql.com/asql/core/views.py", line 22, in <module>
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22]     from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, AnonymousRequiredMixin
[Tue Jul 15 14:36:08 2014] [error] [client 70.180.246.22] ImportError: cannot import name AnonymousRequiredMixin
```

**Edit:**

I am using:

```
Django 1.6.5
Python 3.3
django-braces 1.4.0
```

Comment: AnonymousRequiredMixin is new in v1.4 - what version are you using ?

Comment: @karthikr I added what version of django-braces that I'm using.  When I go into the `virtualenv` I can see the `AnonymousRequiredMixin` module class in the `_access.py` file with the other `AccessMixins`.  And also, this import only fails when it gets to the `AnonymousRequiredMixin` part (i updated the import code snippet to show the whole import form `braces.views`), so I am not sure why it is failing.  Any ideas?  Thanks.